# PAGEIOLATCH_SH and WRITELOG waits

Tags: sql-server-2012, performance, wait-types, performance-tuning

We have a slow overnight process which I was asked to look at with the top waits being `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` and `WRITELOG`

I have been collecting information from `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` and can see that I have extremely high readIOStalls but with a low latency of 13ms.   The same is also true for the log file in that it has a large amount of writeIOStalls but with a latency of 1ms

I also collected some memory information and PLE was in the thousands on average with this being a 32GB system I would expect that apart from in one 30min period where it drops right down to 30 before climbing sharply again, at this time lazy write/sec increases to 50 also before reducing to 0.

My question is I would have expected high IO stalls to have associated high latency values.  With this not being the case is the issue memory related or could it be a blocking issue, which direction do I go with this?